# My site is not loading properly in google app in iPhone12 pro when accessed throw a link

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone

Please help me if you have iphone 12 pro ...

My boos (and some of his customers) has an iPhone 12 pro (ios 14.3) and I don't and yu can't install any apps in iphone simulator so debugging this becomes a nightmare.

This problem is specific to [Google's app on iphone](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/google/id284815942) and does not happen anywhere else!

copy this link and open it in the google's app https://intaker.co/debug.html, tap on one of the links. The site won't load property, it seems that the screen size is not correct (it's very small)!! the loading widget is displayed on the corner and then everything is squished in the corner ... But now if you refresh the same page or rotate the phone the page renders properly!!!

Has anyone seen anything slimier to this? Do you have a solution?

UPDATE 1 : I put a fixed 100% width/height div in the page hopping to force it to grow but no luck

UPDATE 2 : If link comes from the same domain this problem does not happen!!! try the links in here https://intakerclientqa1.azurewebsites.net/debug.html they point to the same domain

UPDATE 3 : This is only happening when using this app https://apps.apple.com/us/app/google/id284815942

[image]

UPDATE 4 : Even after updating the device to 14.4 this is still happening, this is how the site is being rendered :

[image]

This happens only the first time and only when arrived from a external link, it works fine if :

- link is typed/pasted in the browser
- page is refreshed
- device orientation is changed

Comment: Didn’t happen to me, did they try to clear their browser history? Maybe you did fix it and it just got cached

Comment: @Niv yes , they even tried it in incognito mod

Comment: Got iPhone 12 Pro with iOS 14.4 and the google app. can’t replicate your issue

Comment: @Niv maybe its fixed in that version ?? the problem is in 14.3, I tell them to update and test again